# Scala Spark version compatibility

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Im trying to configure Scala in IntelliJ IDE

My Scala & Spark Versions in my machine

```
Welcome to Scala 2.12.5 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_121).

apache-spark/2.2.1
```

SBT file

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.5"
resolvers  += "MavenRepository" at "http://central.maven.org/maven2"

libraryDependencies ++= {
  val sparkVersion = "2.2.1"
    Seq( "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion)
}
```

Error Im getting

```
Error:Error while importing SBT project:<br/>...<br/><pre>[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.14.5 ...
[error] (*:ssExtractDependencies) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.12;2.2.1: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.12;1.4.0: not found
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.12;2.2.1: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.12;1.4.0: not found
```

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14220

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*There isn't the version of spark core that you defined in you sbt project available to be downloaded*. You can check [maven dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core) for more info on what versions are available

*As you can see that for spark-core version 2.2.1, the latest version to be downloaded is compiled in Scala 2.11* [info here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11/2.2.1)

So

**either** you change your sbt build file as

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
resolvers  += "MavenRepository" at "http://central.maven.org/maven2"

libraryDependencies ++= {
  val sparkVersion = "2.2.1"
    Seq( "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion)
}
```

**or** define version of build in dependency as

```
libraryDependencies ++= {
  val sparkVersion = "2.2.1"
    Seq("org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % sparkVersion)
}
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Answer (score 0):

`Spark-2.2.1` does not support to `scalaVersion-2.12`. You have to do like this:

> scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
>
> libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core" % "$sparkVersion"

Thanks